# Why am I getting this error for a function that simply adds a value to every integer in a list?

Tags: sml, polyml

Here's my function:

```ml
fun inclist [] 0 = []
  | inclist (l, inc) = map (fn x => x + inc) l;
```

`l` is a list of ints, and I'm trying to add `inc` to each integer in `l`.

But I'm getting these errors

```
Function: inclist : int list * int -> int list
Argument: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] : int list
Reason: Can't unify int list to int list * int (Incompatible types)

Function: inclist [1, 2, 3, 4, ...] : int list
Argument: 1 : int
Reason: Value being applied does not have a function type
```

And I don't understand why because I have an almost identical function that multiplies values together which works just fine.

Comment: That should have given you errors before you even got to applying the function. My poly says "error: This clause has 1 arguments but previous clause(s) had 2". I can reproduce your errors if I make the first clause `inclist ([], 0)`. Did you make a mistake when copying and pasting?

Comment: @Grav, it's been a week, and you've received multiple good answers. It would be good form to accept any answer(s) you feel answer your question.

Answer (score 2):

To clarify the earlier answer, given that the OP's code suggests a very novice level of SML knowledge:

Every SML function takes exactly *one* argument. Now, this sounds crazy because we've all seen functions that take more than one argument. There are two ways to reconcile these two things.

**Currying**

Functions are first class values in SML. We can easily write a fucntion without giving it a name.

```ml
fn x => x + 1
```

We can bind this to a name.

```ml
val add1 = fn x => x + 1
```

These functions have type `int -> int`. This type signature indicates that the function takes an int and returns an int.

There's a convenience syntax for this.

```ml
fun add1 x = x + 1
```

If we want a function to take more than one argument... we can't. But our function that takes an int can return a function that takes an int and returns an int. The type signature of such a function would be `int -> int -> int`.

```ml
val add = fn x => fn y => x + y
```

And again, there is a more convenient syntax for writing this.

```ml
fun add x y = x + y
```

Calling this is simple:

```ml
add 42 27
```

But we can *partially apply* the function. For example, providing `1` to `add` and getting back a function that adds `1` to whatever int sent to it.

```ml
val add1 = add 1
```

**Tuples**

SML's cousin OCaml uses currying almost exclusively. In SML, it's often more idiomatic to use tuples to provide multiple arguments to a function.

A tuple is a single value, but it contains multiple values which may have heterogenous types. Consider a simple tuples of two ints: `(3, 4)`. Syntactically tuples are surrounded by parentheses and the values are separates by commas.

A function that adds two ints like our earlier `add` function but uses tuples would look like:

```ml
fun add (x, y) = x + y
```

In many cases, the space between the function name and the tuple is left out. To those familiar with C-like syntax, this can be misleading with regards to what's actually happening.

```ml
fun add(x, y) = x + y
```

**Your code**

So, looking at the code you've written:

```ml
fun inclist [] 0 = []
  | inclist (l, inc) = map (fn x => x + inc) l;
```

The first line defines a curried function of type `'a list -> int -> 'a list` and the second defines a function of type `int list * int -> int list`.

Since these two signatures don't match, your code cannot compile.

**One more thing**

In your code, you've unnecessarily specialized your pattern-matching.

```ml
fun inclist [] 0 = []
```

You don't need to match the second argument as `0`. Incrementing an empty list by *any* amount will always be an empty list.

Answer (score 2):

That's not your actual code – that code does not produce those messages.
Your actual code looks more like this:

```
fun inclist ([], 0) = []
  | inclist (l, inc) = map (fn x => x + inc) l;

inclist [1,2,3,4,5] 1;
```

with definition clauses of the same shape.
You have defined a function that takes a *pair* of an `int list` and an `int` and returns an `int list`.
As the error message says: `int list * int -> int list`.

Then you try to apply this function to something that is not such a pair.
`inclist [1,2,3,4,5] 1` is the same as `(inclist [1,2,3,4,5]) 1` - it first applies `inclist` to `[1,2,3,4,5]`, and then applies the result - which must be a function - to `1`.

Your first message refers to `inclist [1,2,3,4,5]`, and says that `[1,2,3,4,5]` is not an `int list * int`, which `inclist` needs.

The second message refers to your applying `inclist [1,2,3,4,5]` to `1`, when `inclist [1,2,3,4,5]` is not a function.
(It is slightly peculiar that polyml claims that `inclist [1,2,3,4,5]` is an `int list`, when it has a type error according to the previous message. One possible explanation is that polyml doesn't bother to check the type of the argument but goes "`inclist` applied to whatever argument is an `int list`".)

The solution is to either pass a pair like the function expects:

```
inclist ([1,2,3,4,5], 1)
```

or to define the function in the "curried" manner:

```
fun inclist [] 0 = []
  | inclist l inc = map (fn x => x + inc) l;

inclist [1,2,3,4,5] 1;
```

On a side note, that first special case is unnecessary.
If you're worried about inefficiency, it makes more sense to special-case `0` than `[]` (avoiding zero-additions in a huge list can be beneficial; only avoiding it with the empty list is pointless).

```
fun inclist (l, 0) = l
  | inclist (l, inc) = map (fn x => x + inc) l;
```

but this will also do the job:

```
fun inclist (l, inc) = map (fn x => x + inc) l;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your first pattern is defined in a curried way, whereas your second pattern uses a tuple way.

This ought to work:

```
fun inclist [] _ = []
  | inclist l inc = map (fn x => x + inc) l;
```

Notice I changed the pattern a bit, since when the list is empty we really don’t care what is the increment.

The truth is that this is probably what `map` already does, so most likely you can do away with the first pattern and just keep your mapping function pattern.

But anyways, now you can do:

```
inclist [] 100; 
inclist [1,2,3] 5;
```

Or alternatively you can define both function patterns using parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

Even this will do...

```
fun inclist inc = map (fn x => x + inc);
```

May be not for now, but at some point in time while exploring the turf of `Higher-Order Functions`, this thing will be quite readily understandable.